# Check locale of current website Magento 2

Tags: magento2, locale

I need to check with php if the currently displayed website is the main one in ENGLISH or it is in INDIAN or ARABIC. How can I do that?

I've searched around but didn't found anything.

in Magento 1 it was super easy

```
$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode(); 

if ($locale == 'en_EN') { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` to get locale code

Inject this class in your constructor

```
/**@var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface **/
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store,
  .....
) {
  $this->_store = $store;
}
```

In your custom method, you can check:

```
$this->_store->getLocaleCode() == 'en_EN';
```

Comment: Note that `getLocaleCode()` is not a method defined by the service contract `Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` and should therefore be considered not to be safely used outside the modules' namespace.

Comment: @GielBerkers yes, thanks! I think we should use `Magento\Store\Model\Store` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use the locale resolver (`Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::getLocale()`):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface
 */
protected $localeResolver;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver
) {
    $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    $currentLocale = $this->localeResolver()->getLocale();        
}
```

Comment: your answer is fine but the localeResolver should not have parenthesis, right?